# How to set a flex item to scroll on x axis

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to get a flex item `.item2` to scroll on the x axis when it's reached a minimum width. The problem I am having is that the whole window is scrolling on the x axis instead of just `.item2`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.item1 {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
.item2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner1, .inner2, .inner3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 350px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="inner3" style="background: orange;">min-width: 350px;</div>
    <div class="inner3" style="background: purple;">min-width: 350px;</div>
    <div class="inner3" style="background: yellow;">min-width: 350px;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? I use `max-width` instead of `min-width` and add `overflow-x:scroll;`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.item1 {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
.item2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2">
    <span>Only this div is supposed to scroll horizontally when larger than max-width. Here's something long: longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried max-width 100vw on .wrap and I also tried adding an inner div to .item2 with a width of 1000px. Overflow-y scrolls properly if needed on .item2, but I'm not sure why overflow-x doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: Hold on, I'm confused. It says it's supposed to scroll sideways when smaller than min-width... do you mean when larger than max-width? Do you want the maximum width to be 1,000 pixels and have it scroll sideways if it needs more room than that?

Comment: No, first one is correct. Sorry for being too vague. I fixed the issue by setting .item2 to flex and setting a min-width on it's inner divs.

Comment: Great, glad you got it figured out!